# Rendering using DirectX

Tags: c++, directx, render

I'm a little new at programming in directX. So far, I have used this code block for rendering. This code is a sample code from my tutorial.

[image]

With this code, we will draw a sprite once after updating frame 2 times. Particularly, when a character stands at position A and in next frame, it will move to position B. But now with this code `_d3ddv->BeginScene()` will return false, then it will not draw anything. In next frame, it will move to position C then `_d3ddv->BeginScene()` will return true, so it will draw.

With this process, I skip a frame with position B. So what should I do now?  Is it true or wrong?

Comment: Post the relevant code here. Also, look at the remarks section from this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174350(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Also remember, ``BeginScene`` and ``EndScene`` return ``HRESULT`` values so don't compare it with boolean values. Use ``SUCCEEDED`` and ``FAILED`` macros to check if those APIs succeeded or not